# Can Google barcode reader be used without play services installed on a phone?

Tags: google-play-services, barcode-scanner, firebase-mlkit

I have an embedded phone application where the phone is running Android 7 without any GMS apps, including play services, since it is not a GMS certified device.

Can I use the Google barcode reading SDK on this device, or does it require Google Play Services to run?

Comment: Your alternative would be using 3rd party libraries/APIs as stated in these related SO posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43013047/5995040) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39103294/5995040).

Comment: I haven't seen a Yes/No answer to this question. Just that there are alternatives. Is the answer that you MUST have google play services installed to use Google's mobile vision SDK (barcode reading)?

Comment: Yup that is correct, if you will be using Google bar code reader you will be needing Google Play Services to run it (which you'll see if you tried their [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/bar-codes/#0)). If you don't plan on using Google Play Services you'll have to use 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be two options here:

**Route 1 - Using Google Bar Code Reader**

If you will be going to this route, one prerequisite will be: you have to use Google Play Services since you'll be using a service from Google (Google Mobile Vision SDK). Try checking their [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/bar-codes/#0), you'll see all the prerequisite libraries you have to use.

**Route 2 - Not using  Google Play Services (GPS)**

As the route says, this will be using external or 3rd party libraries.

References:

[Scan QR code without using google play services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871797/scan-qr-code-without-using-google-play-services/43013047#43013047)

[How to install the barcode scanning library without a google account?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39103294/5995040)